# Unable to process binding "event: function(){return {change:flagSalesOrderItemAsEdited} }"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am currently doing a Pluralsight course on Knockout and MVC (called Parent-Child Data with EF, MVC, Knockout, Ajax, and Validation) which I have been very impressed with, but suddenly I get this bug which has so far been a show stopper for me.
Not only is it a problem in my code, it is also a bug in the very code downloaded from Pluralsight that I saw working on their video!
So in the Edit Partial View I have:

```
<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

<p data-bind="text: MessageToClient"></p>

<div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="CustomerName">Customer Name:</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="CustomerName" id="CustomerName"
               data-bind="value: CustomerName, event: {change: flagSalesOrderAsEdited}"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="PONumber">P.O. Number:</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="PONumber" id="PONumber"
               data-bind="value: PONumber, event: {change: flagSalesOrderAsEdited}"/>
    </div>
</div>
<table class="table table-stripe">
    <tr>
        <th>Product Code</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Unit Price</th>
        <th><button data-bind="click: addSalesOrderItem" class="btn btn-info btn-xs">Add</button></th>
    </tr>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: SalesOrderItems">
        <tr>
            <td class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control input-sm"
                    data-bind="value: ProductCode, event: {change: flagSalesOrderItemAsEdited}, hasfocus: true" />
            </td>
            <td class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control input-sm"
                       data-bind="value: Quantity, event: {change: flagSalesOrderItemAsEdited}" />
            </td>
            <td class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control input-sm"
                       data-bind="value: UnitPrice, event: {change: flagSalesOrderItemAsEdited}" />
            </td>
            <td class="form-group">Delete</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<p><button data-bind="click: save" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button></p>
<p>
    <a href="/" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">&laquo; Back to List</a>
</p>
```

and I apply bindings;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var salesOrderViewModel = new SalesOrderViewModel(@Html.Raw(data));
    ko.applyBindings(salesOrderViewModel);
</script>
```

In my javascript file I have

```
var ObjectState = {
    Unchanged: 0,
    Added: 1,
    Modified: 2,
    Deleted: 3
};

var salesOrderItemMapping = {
    'SalesOrderItems': {
        key: function(salesOrderItem) {
            return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(salesOrderItem.salesOrderItemId);
        },
        create: function(options) {
            return new SalesOrderViewModel(options.data);
        }
    }
};

SalesOrderItemViewModel = function(data) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, salesOrderItemMapping, self);

    self.flagSalesOrderItemAsEdited = function() {
        if (self.ObjectState() !== ObjectState.Added) {
            self.ObjectState(ObjectState.Modified);
        }

        return true;
    };
}

SalesOrderViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, salesOrderItemMapping, self);

    self.save = function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Sales/Save",
            type: "POST",
            data: ko.toJSON(self),
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.salesOrderViewModel !== null) {
                    ko.mapping.fromJS(data.salesOrderViewModel, {}, self);
                }

                if (data.newLocation !== undefined && data.newLocation !== null) {
                    window.location.href = data.newLocation;
                }
            }

        });
    }

    self.flagSalesOrderAsEdited = function () {
        if (self.ObjectState() !== ObjectState.Added) {
            self.ObjectState(ObjectState.Modified);
        }

        return true;
    }
```

The mappings are derived from the server side viewModels:

```
namespace SolutionName.Web.ViewModels
{
    public class SalesOrderViewModel : IObjectWithState
    {
        public SalesOrderViewModel()
        {
            this.SalesOrderItems = new ListStack<SalesOrderItemViewModel>();
        }

        public int SalesOrderId { get; set; }
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        public string PONumber { get; set; }
        public string MessageToClient { get; set; }
        public ObjectState ObjectState { get; set; }
        public List<SalesOrderItemViewModel> SalesOrderItems { get; set; } 
    }
}
```

and

```
namespace SolutionName.Web.ViewModels
{
    public class SalesOrderItemViewModel : IObjectWithState
    {
        public int SalesOrderItemId { get; set; }
        public string ProductCode { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
        public int SalesOrderId { get; set; }
        public ObjectState ObjectState { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The error occurs in the table where I have data-binded the flag field:

```
<td class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control input-sm"
                    data-bind="value: ProductCode, event: {change: flagSalesOrderItemAsEdited}, hasfocus: true" />
            </td>
```

I get 'flagSalesOrderItemAsEdited' is undefined
And it falls over the in the knockout script.

```
Unable to process binding "foreach: function(){return SalesOrderItems }"
Message: Unable to process binding "event: function(){return {change:flagSalesOrderItemAsEdited} }"
Message: 'flagSalesOrderItemAsEdited' is undefined

ex.message = "Unable to process binding \"" + bindingKey + ": " + bindings[bindingKey] + "\"\nMessage: " + ex.message;
```

Line 3326 Exception

So how do I fix this?

EDIT
One suggested solution is to use $parent as a prefix in the HTML.
So I tried:

```
    <td class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control input-sm"
               data-bind="value: ProductCode, event: {change: $parent.flagSalesOrderItemAsEdited}, hasfocus: true" />
    </td>
    <td class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control input-sm"
               data-bind="value: Quantity, event: {change: $parent.flagSalesOrderItemAsEdited}" />
    </td>
    <td class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control input-sm"
               data-bind="value: UnitPrice, event: {change: $parent.flagSalesOrderItemAsEdited}" />
    </td>
```

This stopped the exception being thrown. However the method:

```
self.flagSalesOrderAsEdited = function () {
    if (self.ObjectState() !== ObjectState.Added) {
        self.ObjectState(ObjectState.Modified);
    }
```

was NOT invoked. It was as though the class it is in was not instantiated.

Comment: where is `SalesOrderItems array` defined ?

Comment: I have edited my question to answer your question @shu. The SalesOrderItems array is mapped from the Server side classes into client side classes (which I think is one of the clever parts of the course)

Answer (score 1):

try the following.use `$root` while calling a function inside a loop

```
<td class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control input-sm"
                data-bind="value: ProductCode, event: {change: $root.flagSalesOrderItemAsEdited}, hasfocus: true" />
</td>
```

We can also use `$parent` which is the immeditely outside the current context. 
More info on [`binding context`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html)

Comment: I have had to untick this answer. The solution did stop the exception from being thrown. But the problem I have is that the SalesOrderItemViewModel class does not appear to be instantiated. The intention is that the user sees a list of Sales Order Items and modifies one of them. Then the self.flagSalesOrderAsEdited function is invoked so that on the server side the database updates the value. However this function is NOT invoked, implying the class has not been instantiated.

Comment: I am wondering if this is a problem with ie11. Unfortunately company policy does not let me test this with other browsers.

Comment: @arame3333 , No problem , I have not noticed that in the code , Glad you find the solution.

Comment: I didn't find the solution. I am still stuck. Using $root or $parent stops the exception from being thrown, but the functions in the SalesOrderItemViewModel  class are not invoked.

Comment: @arame3333 can you please update the question with the changes,i guess what could be the issue,why do not you move `flagSalesOrderAsEdited ` method inside the `SalesOrderViewModel ` which is actually binded to the `html`

Comment: The only changes I made were what you suggested. What the course is teaching me is how to replicate the viewmodels for SaleOrders and SaleOrderItems on the server via mapping onto the client, and that is why there are 2 viewmodels on the client.

Comment: @arame3333 can you update the question with the chnages

Comment: Is the loop is working as I can see there is nor `SalesOrderItems  observable array` in side the `SalesOrderViewModel  `

Comment: The code for salesOrderItemMapping is meant to achieve that. I do not think it is working but it is how it is done in the course I am following. I want to get this to work but I do not know how to.